# iOS7 xCode5 how to resolve "invalid product ID" for in app purchases in 2014?

Tags: ios7, in-app-purchase, xcode5, skproduct

I'm trying to implement in-app purchases in one of my apps, and have an issue where I get no products returned when I send a product request for sandbox testing. I see a lot of very old posts, like this one ([invalid product id from 2010](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/)). **What am I doing wrong with my in app purchase setup?** Is there **any recent tutorials** on how to configure xCode5 to use in app purchasing?

```
- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
{

    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:self.productID ];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];

    // we will release the request object in the delegate callback
}
```

Here's the callback for the product request:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    NSArray *products = response.products;

    for(id object in products)
    {
//handle valid products
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }
    [hud hide:YES];

}
```

Using this option created a duplicate app id with the same number, but different name on hte developer portal. I cannot delete that app ID.
[image]

[image]

This is the first consumable in app purchase, no need to host content. The app is in "ready to upload binary stage". It has been over 24 hours since I created the in app purchase via itunesconnect

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

Turns out when I created the product in iTunesConnect, I called it  "product", when it should've been "com.mysite.product"

[image]